# Utility to add visual effects to Windows

Tags: windows, visual-effects

I have *no idea* how to go about looking for this utility, so I though I would ask here. I recall a small utility that would add Compiz like effects on Windows. It was relatively small, and was released a few years ago. Does anyone know what it was called, and where I can get it?

EDIT: It does not add the desktop cube or window switchers. It is more like the Compiz panel, where you can check/uncheck the effects that you want. The effects are applied to windows, and is stuff like fade, blur, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the program. It's called Nimi Visuals. http://mynimi.net/p,Why-love-Nimi-Visuals.html

Answer (score 0):

The only one I remember is Desk Hedron. From the page, it looks like it only supports Win2k and WinXP.

[Desk Hedron Link](http://deskhedron.en.softonic.com/)

Comment: No. That's not it. I edited the question to try to describe it in more detail.

Comment: @ Soumya92 The only other ones I found were WinSplit Revolution and Yod’m 3D. There is also this link although I couldn't verify it due to the network I'm on: [3D Effects](http://thegabfather.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/compiz-fusion-in-windows/)

Comment: Nod the one I was looking for either. These are good programs to be sure, but not what I am looking for.